# Multiple Excel Sheets in One Excel File

Tags: c#, excel, forms, window

I would like to create 4 sheets in xlWorkbook;

```
     private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {           
           Excel.Application xlApp;
           Excel.Workbook  xlWorkbook;
           Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
           xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                  // Code Logic 
           }
```

I tried

```
          Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
          xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
```

But doesn't work out. Could any one help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fczc37s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet2;
xlWorkSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
```

Do this four times, and you'll get 4 sheets.